# Sum different cell range values based on other cell range that contains consecutive rows

Tags: vba, excel, sum, formula

I have name list in A:A that contains 2, 3, 4 or any number of duplicate rows for that list. I need to get sum of B:B separately for each name. Can anyone help me to do this.

Note. This list contains more than 1500 names

```
Sam   50
Sam   15
Sam   25
Jim   10
Jim   15
Ann   5
```

I need the answer like this

```
Sam   90
Jim   25
Ann    5
```

Comment: So copy and paste your list of names in a new column, Go to DATA-->Remove Duplicates.  The use SUMIF as @findwindow stated.  So lets assume you put the names in Column F starting in Row 2.  `=SUMIF(A:A,F2,B:B)` then copy down.

Comment: Thanks findwindow for the help. It was worked for me.

Comment: Also thanks Gary's Student for correcting my quiz

Comment: Thanks Scott Craner for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not enough reputation for post a comment, so i post an answer...
Why not use a pivot table? Take a look at the [Office support](https://support.office.com/en-GB/Article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576).
Simply:

- Be sure the table have a header row
- Select a cell inside the table (for example cell A3)
- menu *insert* and *pivot table*
- The interval will be filled automatically (check if it's correct), select where to put the new table (new sheet or where in the current sheet) and *OK*
- Put the "names column" in the *row labels* field and the "numbers column" in the *sum values* field

You will have what you need without formulas/macros

Comment: I tried this as well EttoreP & this one also worked for me. Thanks for the help.